# How best to model reservation/appointments database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, associations

I'm looking to write some sort of Rails app to help users book time slots at a restaurant. How can this be modeled in such a way so that it can be reservations can be displayed and booked through the browser? I have two models:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reservations


class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant

    attr_accessible :name, :date, :time
```

At first I toyed with a using a hash within the Restaurant model to store availability, using dates as keys. But then I realized that Rails databases must serialize hashes, and I'd like to make sure there isn't a better way to go about this before I dive into that stuff.

I'm using Postgres (if that's relevant). Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your basic model structure is fine. Note that `attr_accessible` is not current best practices, as of Rails 4. (It has been replaced by [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters))

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter too much about what database you are using (even though PG is a solid choice) but the general engineering that is truly important.

I won't give you a copy paste answer but hopefully give you some direction.

So a **Restaurant** can have many **Reservations** throughout the day. I assume each restaurant can only hold so many people and thus have some type of "*reservation limit*" and **Reservations** cannot overlap.

Because of the constraints I imagine your 2 model method will work. You just need to figure out exactly how they must interact to work as you plan.

**Restaurants** should be able to keep track of open times/vacancies (or whatever important details). While **Reservations** will keep track of the number of people in the party, time, etc.

Your initial relationship looks to be well defined. But the other answer does correctly point out the new Rails 4 preferred method.